# What jQuery function would access the next Table and the next Input[type=submit] button in this markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a page with where mp3 products are being sold. Each page represents an album entity. 
At a minimum each page contains an album product and at least one or more mp3’s available for purchase as a separate products. 
Each album and mp3 product has it’s on form with an input[type=submit] button that functions as an ‘add to cart’ button.

Some mp3’s have been designated as album only. This is done w/ markup via a span tag.

```
<span class=“album-only-tag”>True</span>
```

Based on that markup, I’m trying to write some javascript that will do 3 things:

• remove the table containing the price

• disable the submit button, so user’s cannot add to cart (they instead have to purchase the album).

•change the value of the input[type=“submit”] to read as ‘album only’.

Also, after code runs as per mp3 it needs to stop, and leave the other price table & ’add to cart’ buttons intact.

My jQuery code here is not working. My use of the next() function is incorrect i guess.

What jQuery function should i use to access the next table and the next form input[type=“submit”] button in this markup?

btw - the markup here has been abbreviated.

```
<div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
 <div  class="ds- 1col node node--ltv-track-ii node-teaser node-product-type node--ltv-track-ii node-product-type-teaser node-ltv-track-ii-teaser view-mode-teaser node--teaser node--ltv-track-ii--teaser clearfix">
 <span class="album-only-tag">True</span>
 <table class="commerce-price-rrp-your-price">
  <tr class="odd">
   <td class="webprice-title">Price</td>
   <td class="webprice-total">$5.95</td> </tr>
</table>
<div class="field field-name-field-product">
  <form class="commerce-add-to-cart commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-1909 commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-1909" action="/ltvalbums/wah/lokaha" method="post" id="commerce-cart-add-to-cart-form-1909" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<div><input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1909" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-qbskkxq4JIW0IEzmvAgwqow7QylhhgdtnfmqbHrdMe0" />
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_1909" />
  <div id="edit-line-item-fields--2" class="form-wrapper"></div>        <input type="submit" id="edit-submit--2" name="op" value="Add to cart" class="form-submit" />
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Huge thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Can you post the jquery code you have already tried

Comment: Could you share the full source code please? We need to know your html structure, as this is important to select the correct elements. This way we can provide better answer for you

Answer (score 1):

Here is you go,

```
$('.album-only-tag').each(function () {
    var table = $(this).next('table');
    var submitBtn = table.next('div').find('input[type="submit"]');

    // disable the add to cart button
    submitBtn.prop('disabled', true);

    // change the text to "Album only"
    submitBtn.val("album only");

    // remove the table
    table.remove();
});
```

Comment: @TopTomato, did you debugged this code? is variables `table` and `submitBtn` got desired elements?